# Django models - related objects validation

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, model

I'm wondering how to have validations for related objects. To my surprise I haven't found much relevant information on this.

For example:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
   categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
   price_sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)
   price_rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)
   price_vacation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
   value = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Image(models.Model):
   listing = models.ForeignKey('Listing')
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

- How can I make sure that at least one `category` is set, there are no
  duplicates for the listing?
- How can I make sure that if one of the `categories` is '*sale*', `price_sale` must be set or else set to null?
- How can I make sure that at least one `image` is inserted but not more
  than say 10 images?

I'm thinking this should be done in the model in case I choose to input data aside from forms (something like parsing a feed), would this be correct? I tried dealing with `clean()` but it requires a PK before letting me deal with m2m relationships, etc.

Bonus question: Why would I choose to limit a field using choices rather than limiting by FK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly creating your mapping table, and have your ManyToMany relationship go `through` this model.  Since it is a normal Django model you should be able to define most of your validation logic within its `clean` method.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', through='CategoryListing')
    price_sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)
    price_rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)
    price_vacation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class CategoryListing(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing)

    def clean(self):
        # validation logic
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: This would more for validating a join table row by itself and not in relation to `listing` no? I'd like to prevent a `listing` to be inserted without having at least one m2m relation.